# Why wouldn't a modified Bellman Ford work for Max Product Path/Currency Arbitrage in a directed graph?

Tags: shortest-path, dijkstra, directed-graph, bellman-ford

Problem Statement: Let c<sub>1</sub>,c<sub>2</sub>,...c<sub>n</sub> be various currencies. Between two currencies c<sub>i</sub> and c<sub>j</sub>, there is an exchange rate r<sub>i,j</sub> > 0. These exchange rates satisfy the condition that r<sub>i,j</sub> * r<sub>j,i</sub> < 1.

When given a set of exchange rates r<sub>i,j</sub> and two currencies s and t, give an efficient algorithm to find the most advantageous sequence of currency exchanges for converting s into t.

What I've tried:
I modified the standard Bellman Ford Algorithm to relax and edge(u,v) if v .d is smaller than than u.d*w where u.d represent the product coming from s to u so far.

Here's a pseudocode snippet of what I did.

```
for i in range(len(G.Vertices)):

   for edge in G.Edges:
       u = edge.u
       v = edge.v
       w = edge.w

       if v.d < u.d * w:
          v.p = u  #keeping track of parent
          v.d = u.d*w
```

This worked fine for the test cases given in the problem but I was told by my evaluator that my solution would fail in some cases (they did not provide any counterexamples). Instead, I was told to take log(1/w) and run Dijkstra/Bellman Ford without modification.

I understand how and why the log(1/w) solution works but what I fail to understand is which cases my solution would fail.